# How to change the Input Name based on the dropdown selection in html form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a HTML form which **changes its form action based on the drop down selection** but input name remains same.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="car.php" method="GET">
Select Your Option :
<select onChange="this.form.action=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
      <option value='car.php'>Car Name</option>
      <option value='bike.php'>Bike Name</option>
      <option value='laptop.php'>Laptop Name</option>
      <option value='place.php'>Place Name</option>
      <option value='mobile.php'>Mobile Name</option>
    </select>
Enter your query                 // I want to change this also
<input id="Value" name="Value" type="text">
<button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit Query</button>
```

If I select `Car Name` and enter `Maruti` then value is passed like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/car.php?Value=Maruti
```

If I select `Bike Name` and enter `Honda` then value is passed like this :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/bike.php?Value=Honda
```

---

My problem is I have to name the column as "Value" in all the 5 database which stores all the information regarding all this, which I want to avoid.

I want, If I select `Car Name` and enter `Maruti` then value should pass like this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/car.php?car=Maruti
```

If I select `Bike Name` and enter `Honda` then value should pass like this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/bike.php?bike=Honda
```

---

What changes should be made in the code to achieve this goal?

If this can also happen then its very nice otherwise no problem.

In the form it is written `Enter your query`. I want the same change to happen here. If I select Car Name then it should be `Enter you car`. If I select Bike Name then it should be `Enter your bike`... and so on.

**UPDATE**

Little modification I need. When selecting car, the input name is changing to car, the form action is changing to car.php and query to Enter your car. But If I want to change the name like this then what should I do? When I will select anything say bike then form action will be changed to bike.php, But I want input name to be different say USY and Enter your bike to Enter your Serial No. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code now and got ur exact requirement now and i hope this will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").change(function(){
                var str=$(this).val(); // On Change get the option value
                $("form").attr("action",str);
                var res=str.split(".");
                $("#input1").attr("name",res[0]);
                $(".title").html("Enter your "+res[0]+" Name."); // Add this below  $("input").attr("name",res[0]); 
                if(res[0]=='bike')
                {
                    var title2="XYZ";
                    var title3="Serial No";                 
                }
                else if(res[0]=='laptop')
                {
                    var title2="ABC";
                    var title3="Model No";                  
                }
                else if(res[0]=='place')
                {
                    var title2="KLM";
                    var title3="Area";                  
                }
                else if(res[0]=='mobile')
                {
                    var title2="FGH";
                    var title3="Brand";                 
                }
                $("#input2").attr("name",title2);
                $("#input3").attr("name",title3);
                $(".title2").html("Enter your "+title3);

            });             
        });         
    </script>
    <form action="car.php" method="GET">
Select Your Option :
<select value="car.php">
      <option value='car.php'>Car Name</option>
      <option value='bike.php'>Bike Name</option>
      <option value='laptop.php'>Laptop Name</option>
      <option value='place.php'>Place Name</option>
      <option value='mobile.php'>Mobile Name</option>
    </select>
<span class="title2">Enter your Color</span> 
<input name="WER" id="input2" type="text">
<button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit Query</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You didn't understood my question... I don't need 2 more input field...
When I will select the car... the form action will be car.php, the query will be "Enter your Color", input Id will be WER, if I will give green then URL will look like this http://mywebsite.com/car.php?WER=green, for bike.... form action bike.php, "Enter your Serial No" , input id will be XYZ, so if entered 2002 then the URL will look like this http://mywebsite.com/car.php?XYZ=2002 and so on...

Comment: Did you understand my question ? I will explain it again if you donot understood...

Comment: Bro... you still didn't understand my question... I don't want 2 input field... for ex- when I will select car. There should not be two input field like "Enter your car name " and "Enter your color". There should be only 1 " Enter your color". Let I enter green then URL should look like this  mywebsite.com/car.php?WER=green because in my database the column which contains the color is named WER.

Comment: Ohh sorry remove the second input box alone already I GOT THE ANSWER unwantedly placed the second input box

Comment: Then remove the first input field thats it problem is over

Comment: If I knew that, I would have already done that... I don't know javascript.. Please edit the answer..

Comment: When I am selecting Bike. The query should be " Enter your serial no" not "Enter your XYZ". The value passed is correct http://mywebsite.com/bike.php?XYZ=2002 because column in database is named XYZ ...

Similarly for all other also. For example when selecting Laptop, it should be written " Enter your Model No" not "Enter your ABC". For place " Enter your area". For Mobile, "Enter your brand".... The value passed is correct for all.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to not use JavaScript embedded into HTML attributes. Other than that, you can change the name attribute in the same `change` handler where you're modifying the action.

```js
document.getElementById('Type').addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
  var type = this.selectedOptions[0].value;
  console.dir(this);
  document.getElementById('Value').setAttribute('name', type);
  document.getElementById('QueryName').textContent = type;
  this.form.action = type + ".php";
});
```

```html
<form action="car.php" method="GET">
Select Your Option :
<select id="Type">
      <option value='car' selected>Car Name</option>
      <option value='bike'>Bike Name</option>
      <option value='laptop'>Laptop Name</option>
      <option value='place'>Place Name</option>
      <option value='mobile'>Mobile Name</option>
    </select>
Enter your <span id="QueryName">car</span>
<input id="Value" name="car" type="text">
<button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit Query</button>
```

EDIT: If you want everything to be different as said in comments, you can use an object to hold the values. For example,

```
var setup = {
  car: {
    action: 'mycar.php',
    param: 'DFS',
    query: 'color'
  },
  ...
};
```

and then instead of directly using the option's value, pull from this object based on the selected option.

Comment: This code is not working. Everytime http://www.mywebsite.com/car.php is getting selected...

Comment: Also what the code is doing right now, your code also want to do the same thing. What I want to achieve is not there !

Comment: Use the inspector to see that, in fact, it is not true that `car.php` is selected (but also `laptop.php`, if Laptop Name is selected). Additionally, note that the `name="car"` also changes (into, say, `name="laptop"`). I admit I overlooked the "Enter your ..." part; I will fix it in a minute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code is working according to my question.... Little modification I need is.... when selecting car, the input name is changing to car, the form action is changing to car.php and query to Enter your car.... But If I want to change the name like this then what should I do....? when I will select anything say bike then form action will be changed to bike.php or I can change it from value field to whatever I want... that I will change according to the file... but I want input name to be different say USY and Enter your bike to Enter your Serial No... what should I do

Comment: In you code you have made it to change input name , form action and Enter your [query] by the same name, car or bike etc.... But I want all to be different for all... like when car selected, the form action should be mycar.php, input name should be , DFS and query should be Enter your Color and so on... please help

Comment: Sorry I don't know javascript and I am not able to do this. I don't know where to add the above edited code and what to change in the code for pulling from this object based.... Can you combine all the separate code to one single whole file/code ?

Comment: That's strange. However, "not working" is not nearly descriptive enough for anyone to figure out what is wrong. Could it possibly be caching an old version of the site?

Comment: No, not the older version. I placed your code in a new file to check. The default action 'car.php' and default input name 'car' is passed for all the options. Even the query name is not changing after changing the options... Every time it is 'Enter you car'... you can check it in your mobile in Chrome, UC Browser, Default Android browser, Dolphin browser...

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("select").change(function(){
    var str=$(this).val(); // On Change get the option value
    $("form").attr("action",str);
    var res=str.split(".");
    $("input").attr("name",res[0]);
   });    
  });   
 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 
</head>
<form action="car.php" method="GET">
Select Your Option :
<select value="car.php">
      <option value='car.php'>Car Name</option>
      <option value='bike.php'>Bike Name</option>
      <option value='laptop.php'>Laptop Name</option>
      <option value='place.php'>Place Name</option>
      <option value='mobile.php'>Mobile Name</option>
    </select>
Enter your query                 // I want to change this also
<input id="Value" name="car" type="text">
<button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit Query</button>
</form>
</html>
```

I have used jquery here some few changes in html try it out this one

```
<form action="car.php" method="GET">
Select Your Option :
<select value="car.php">
      <option value='car.php'>Car Name</option>
      <option value='bike.php'>Bike Name</option>
      <option value='laptop.php'>Laptop Name</option>
      <option value='place.php'>Place Name</option>
      <option value='mobile.php'>Mobile Name</option>
    </select>
Enter your query                 // I want to change this also
<input id="Value" name="car" type="text">
<button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit Query</button>
</form>
```

And for Jquery you can use this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select").change(function(){
                var str=$(this).val(); // On Change get the option value
                $("form").attr("action",str);
                var res=str.split(".");
                $("input").attr("name",res[0]);
            });             
        });         
    </script>
```

This works perfectly for me Enjoy :)

Comment: You code is not working. Everything is passed to car.php and value is changing to car for all the options. Like this If I enter 3 then http://www.mywebsite.com/car,php?car=3  for all the options

Comment: Enter you query is still not changing. I have added some update to question. Please change the code accordingly....

Comment: $(".title").html("Enter your "+res[0]+" Name."); // Add this below  $("input").attr("name",res[0]); and <span class="title">Enter your Car Name</span> <!-- Replace Enter Your Query with <span class="title">Enter your Car Name</span> -->

Comment: I have updated the question but you are not changing that in your code !

Comment: UPDATE

Little modification I need. When selecting car, the input name is changing to car, the form action is changing to car.php and query to Enter your car. But If I want to change the name like this then what should I do? When I will select anything say bike then form action will be changed to bike.php, But I want input name to be different say USY and Enter your bike to Enter your Serial No. What should I do ?

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly how the format should be since i couldn't understand exact requirement. show me any screenshot

Comment: In your code if I will select Bike Name then 3 change will happen. Form action will be change to bike.php , Input Name will be changed from car to bike and Enter you query will change to Enter you Bike. All the 3 changes are made by same name bike ! I want that if I will select Bike Name then form action should be bike.php, Input name should be XYZ and Enter your query should be Enter your serial no. This should happens for all others also means I want to change all the 3 with 3 different name according to my wish...

Comment: In your code... I can only understand that if I will change value='car.php' to whatever I want then form action will change accordingly. Changing the car.php will change all the 3 form action, input name and query by the same name bike.php, bike, bike name. I want all the 3 to be of different name... form action, input name and query. Did you understand my problem ?

Comment: So for example for car I want...car.php, WER, Color... for bike...  bike.php, XYZ and Serial No.. for Laptop... laptop.php, ABC and Model No... For Place... place.php, KLM and Area... For mobile... mobile.php, FGH, Brand for the field form action, input name, query respectively....

Comment: I placed your code inside the html head, now it is working... but still I need some modification which I had told you in previous comment...

Comment: Will check it let you know ASAP

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. THe query you have raised is dynamic right?? 

 (i.e.,) I want...car.php, WER, Color... for bike... bike.php, XYZ and Serial No.. for Laptop... laptop.php, ABC and Model No... For Place... place.php, KLM and Area... For mobile... mobile.php, FGH, Brand.

Everything seems to be based dynamically right??